# Managing queue requests with asp.net webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

Is there any way to prevent an especific method of an asp.net webapi from being accessed by more than one request  at the same time? Being more specific I'd like   to manage some thing like FIFO, once a request is being processed  the others should wait up to the one which is processing get finished and then the next one will be processed.

Comment: It sounds like a problem for Mutex, for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22154306/how-to-implement-an-mvc-4-web-app-server-side-mutex